# pymysql just select value and save into variable

Tags: python, mysql, select, pymysql

```
cursor.execute("SELECT price FROM tabel WHERE id = 1600")
print cursor.fetchone()
```

gives me the output

```
{u'price': u'4345.6'}
```

how can I select just the value 4345.6 and save it in a variable to do some math?

Comment: This is basic python dictionary handling. Consider reading intro docs and tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily solve this by the following peace of code.

```
data = cursor.fetchone() #get the data in data variable
value = float(data['price']) # load the data into value with conversion of its type
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dictionary.Get Method:

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp

```
cursor.execute("SELECT price FROM tabel WHERE id = 1600") 
resultdict = cursos.fetchone() 
result = resultdict.get("price") 
print(result)
```